# Ruby included objects best practice

Tags: ruby, oop

First, hello everyone,

I want to known about object inclusion best practice in ruby.
Let's describe the context:

- Object A is a "root" object
- Object B is an independent object but needs to access to A attributes. So to initialize it, I do "B.new(instance_of_A, other_param)" and I store the instance of A in an attr_accessor
- Object C is an independent object but needs to access to B attributes. So, I use same way to initialize it (passing an instance of B)

The result is that I end up with nested object that could be very very large and repeat themselves.

Is there any other solution / pattern to do the same but in a cleaner way ?
Is there any good example of these kind of implementation ?

Thank you !

Here is a basic example, but imagine that the object are way bigger with a lot of properties.

```
require 'awesome_print'

class A
  attr_accessor :title

  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
  end
end

class B
  attr_accessor :a, :level

  def initialize(a, level)
    @a = a
    @level = level

    # Here, I need to access to a.title
  end
end

class C
  attr_accessor :b, :name

  def initialize(b, name)
    @b = b
    @name = name

    # Here, I need to access to b.level
  end
end

a = A.new 'test'

b1 = B.new a, 1
b2 = B.new a, 2
b3 = B.new a, 3

c1 = C.new b1, 'one one'
c2 = C.new b1, 'one two'
c3 = C.new b1, 'one three'

ap c1
ap c2
ap c3

c4 = C.new b2, 'two one'
c5 = C.new b2, 'two two'
c6 = C.new b2, 'two three'

# ... etc
```

Result seems dirty to me (inclusion of big objects in other big objects)

```
#<C:0x000001011e9680 @b=#<B:0x000001011e9720 @a=#<A:0x000001011e9748 @title="test">, @level=1>, @name="one one">
#<C:0x000001011e9630 @b=#<B:0x000001011e9720 @a=#<A:0x000001011e9748 @title="test">, @level=1>, @name="one two">
#<C:0x000001011e95b8 @b=#<B:0x000001011e9720 @a=#<A:0x000001011e9748 @title="test">, @level=1>, @name="one three">
```

Comment: Hmm, for me I would find it easier if you could provide a somewhat more concrete example of a solution you aren't happy with, and then maybe I could take a stab at an improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing about object orientation is that you encapsulate data, methods and also other objects in order to create abstractions. More abstractions can make it easier for you to reason about your project, but it also adds complexity and makes your project more complicated. I particularly find it quite hard to balance these two out. That only comes with years and years of practice.

If three levels of encapsulation may seem too much, try to see [dependencies as a code smell](http://qualityisspeed.blogspot.nl/2014/09/beyond-solid-dependency-elimination.html).

Do all of the objects represent a meaningful, useful abstraction? For example:

- B seems to be using `A#title` for something
- B exposes A for C to use
- B exposes `level` for C to use

Here, B seem to just be taking A and including a level attribute, so that it can be used by C. Does this abstraction mean something useful?

Could we simplify the problem if C received an A object, a `level` and a `name`?

```
class A
  attr_reader :title # Do you really need outside code to change this?

  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
  end
end

class C
  attr_reader :level, :name

  def initialize(a, level, name)
    @a = a
    @level = level
    @name = name

    # Here, you access a.title to do whatever you did in B
  end

  def title
    @a.title
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, I see the point, but sometimes, it is impossible to "skip" an object like this. Let's take an example of a website. A = site, B = Page, C = tag. A site has several pages, a page has zero, one or several tags and a tag belongs to one or several different pages. And for "page" and "tag", they need to access to site.url, for example.

Comment: Why does a tag need to know the URL? Does the page depend on the tags or the tags depend on the page? Like you said, a tag is an object that can be used in several different pages. As such, the URL seems not to be a tag's business.